# Having a different display on the Laptop and HDMI TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, tv

I need help in getting my Laptop and TV (HDMI) displays working.

Is it possible to be doing stuff on the laptop without showing on the TV, just like using a projector and a laptop?

For example: Show a page on the HDMI TV and be working on a different page on the Laptop?

Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `Extended Desktop` instead of a `Mirrored Desktop`. Hopefully your driver and your graphics chip on your laptop will support it.

**Go To Windows 7 Display Control Panel:**

- On the Windows taskbar, click <kbd>Start</kbd>.
- Click `Control Panel`.
- Click `Appearance and Personalization`.
- Click `Personalization`.
- Click `Display Settings`.
- From the monitor drop-down menu, select the second display.
- Mark the `Extend the desktop onto this monitor` checkbox.
- Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Attaching a screenshot, In your case the Second Monitor will be your HDMI TV

[image: Extended Desktop]

**If your computer screen does not appear on your LCD, Plasma or Projector then you may need to:**

- Lower the resolution setting in the display settings
- If you’re using a laptop press and hold the <kbd>FN</kbd> key on the bottom left of your keyboard and the <kbd>Fkey</kbd> on your keyboard that has an image of a screen on it. Usually <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd>.
- Restart your computer
- On the LCD, Plasma TV or projector that you are using ensure that you have selected the correct source, using either the remote or the buttons on the set. Please refer to the user manual to ensure you are pressing the right button for this.

**You can go to this [website](http://knowhow.com/article.dhtml?articleReference=244&country=uk) for additional help.**